# Magento2: How to show breadcrumb on home page?

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs, home-page

How to show breadcrumb on home page?
I have enabled breadcrumb option for all cms page from the Admin panle. But it's not apply for home page.
What is the standard way to display breadcrumb on home page also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding below code in you `cms_index_index.xml` under `<body>` tag

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
            <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Done......... :)