# Breadcrumbs on pages other than category/product detail

Tags: magento2, layout, breadcrumbs

I've already seen a few posts here how to add breadcrumbs on pages like customer page or contact page (like [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/106321/70510) or [that](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206561/70510)). But is there any way to add them to all pages that are missing them without having to edit all the layout xmls?

Comment: did you find the answer yet? thanks

Comment: no not yet. it is possible to put it in the layouts for each page separately but that's not really what i intended. i found [this](https://github.com/tzyganu/m2-breadcrumbs) module but it is 4 years old so it might need some changes but i didn't manage to dig into that yet